# I bind a custom FBO, but what I draw goes beyond it

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2, fbo

I've made a simple testcase. What I do, in short:

- I have a `QQuickFramebufferObject` subclass called MyItem. It uses the `CombinedDepthStencil` Attachment type.
- I create an instance of MyItem on window hover and destroy it on window unhover
- In `MyItemRenderer::render()` I create a local FBO and draw a triangle to it
- This local FBO uses a custom FBO wrapper class instead of QOpenGLFramebufferObject, to narrow down the problem. The problem occurs with QOpenGLFramebufferObject too, though.

The expected behavior is that nothing should ever be drawn to the window. But instead, on the **second** time you hover the window (after launching the app), the triangle is drawn to the window.

**My code:**

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QQuickFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLTexture>
#include "fbo.h"

class MyItem : public QQuickFramebufferObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Renderer* createRenderer() const;
};

class MyItemRenderer : public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer, protected QOpenGLFunctions {
public:
    MyItemRenderer() {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();

        m_program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/shader.vert.glsl");
        m_program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/shader.frag.glsl");
        m_program.link();
    }

    void render() {
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        Fbo fbo(m_size);

        m_program.bind();
        fbo.bind();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        paintGeometry();

        framebufferObject()->bind();

        m_window->resetOpenGLState();
    }

    void paintGeometry() {
        QVector<QVector2D> vertices = { QVector2D(0, 0), QVector2D(1, 0), QVector2D(1, 1) };

        m_program.enableAttributeArray("aPos");
        m_program.setAttributeArray("aPos", vertices.constData());
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
        m_program.disableAttributeArray("aPos");
    }

    QOpenGLFramebufferObject* createFramebufferObject(const QSize &size) {
        QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
        format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
        return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size, format);
    }

private:
    QOpenGLShaderProgram m_program;
    QQuickWindow* m_window;
    QSize m_size;

protected:
    void synchronize(QQuickFramebufferObject* qqfbo) {
        MyItem* parentItem = (MyItem*)qqfbo;
        m_window = parentItem->window();
        m_size = QSize(parentItem->width(), parentItem->height());
    }
};

QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer* MyItem::createRenderer() const {
    return new MyItemRenderer();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MyItem>("MyItem", 1, 0, "MyItem");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import MyItem 1.0

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    id: root

    Loader {
        active: mouseArea.containsMouse
        sourceComponent: MyItem {
            parent: root
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        hoverEnabled: true
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

*shader.frag.glsl*:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.40, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

*shader.vert.glsl*:

```
attribute highp vec2 aPos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

*fbo.h*:

```
#ifndef FBO_H
#define FBO_H

#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLTexture>

class Fbo : public QOpenGLFunctions {
public:
    Fbo(const QSize &size)
        : m_colorAttachment(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D)
    {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();

        glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_id);

        m_colorAttachment.setSize(size.width(), size.height());
        m_colorAttachment.setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA8_UNorm);
        m_colorAttachment.allocateStorage();
        bind();
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_colorAttachment.textureId(), 0);
    }
    ~Fbo() {
        glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &m_id);
    }

    void bind() {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_id);
    }

private:
    GLuint m_id;
    QOpenGLTexture m_colorAttachment;
};

#endif
```

**Any ideas?**

Note that I've ran the testcase in the CodeXL OpenGL debugger and it has found no OpenGL errors. Same with Qt's `QOpenGLDebugLogger` mechanism.

Comment: 2 "off-topic close" votes? How can this be offtopic? o_O

Comment: Maybe because you talk about something that happens when hovering but (at least I) can't see any code that looks like handling a hover event.

Comment: @BDL: It's just written in QML-idiomatic (declarative) style :) See the `active: mouseArea.containsMouse` line.